# NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ошибка в коде при попытке привязать кнопку с прыжком к игроку

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здраствуйте, я делаю игру, и хочу сделать так что бы песонаж прыгал при нажатии на кнопку. Но у меня в коде вылазит ошибка. Но я не понимаю что не так, вот код для персонажа и код для кнопки

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

public class HeroMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float horisontalSpeed;
    float speed;
   
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isGrounded = false;
    public int jumpforce;
    private JumpButton JumpButtonScript;
    private GameObject Button;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Button = GameObject.Find("Button");
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
            speed = -horisontalSpeed;
        } else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
             speed = horisontalSpeed;
        }
        
    }
    void Update()
    {

     Jump();
     
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        GameObject.Find("Button").GetComponent<JumpButton>();

        if(JumpButtonScript.isPressed && !isGrounded)
     {
     gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpforce);
     JumpButtonScript.isPressed = false;
     isGrounded = false;
     JumpButtonScript.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     } else if (!isGrounded) 
     {
      JumpButtonScript.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     }
        
        

    }
}
```

Код для кнопки :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class JumpButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public bool isPressed = false;
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        isPressed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GameObject.Find("Button").GetComponent<JumpButton>()
```

Скорее это просто лишний код.
Более правильный вариант будет:

```
JumpButtonScript = Button.GetComponent<JumpButton>()
```

Сама ошибка возникает из-за попытки взаимодействия с переменной без присвоенного значения:

```
JumpButtonScript.isPressed = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю должно быть так:

```
JumpButtonScript = GameObject.Find("Button").GetComponent<JumpButton>();

if(JumpButtonScript.isPressed && !isGrounded) ...
// .......
```

То есть компонент-то нашли через `GetComponent`, а вот сложить её никуда не сложили. Поэтому `JumpButtonScript.isPressed` выдаёт ошибки, потому что `JumpButtonScript` не определён.

Comment: хм, ошибка до сих пор висит, но игра запускается и кнопка не придает признаков жизни просто нажимается

Comment: Очистите консоль и перезапустите игру. точно?

Comment: @Александр а если так `JumpButtonScript  = Button.GetComponent<JumpButton>();`?

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но персонаж не прыгает при нажатии.. Может я что то упустил.

Comment: Возможно. Но это  уже другая проблема